# Store number of clicks in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, click

> I am working on a project which includes image gallery.Now I want to store number of clicks/counts value into my database(developed in MySQL). I tried to do it in my own way, but problem is count/clicks value for all the images are stored in the database as same value.
>
> The code given below is in the file **main.php** which displays images that is retrieved from database.The **picture.php** is the one that retrieves images from database. I have appended the code to count the number of clicks in **picture.php** so that it counts whenever the image is clicked.

**main.php**

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM files";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         echo "<div class=single>
               <div class=wrap>
                   <a href=picture.php?fid=".$offer_id.">
                       <img src=picture.php?fid=".$offer_id."\">
                   </a>
               </div>
               </div>";
    }
```

**picture.php**

```
    if(isset($_GET['fid']))
    {
         include "connect.php";
         $fid=$_GET['fid'];
         $query="SELECT * FROM offers_em WHERE o_id =$fid";
         $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

         $sql="UPDATE offers_em SET count+=1 WHERE o_id=".$fid;
         $sql2=mysql_query($sql);
         
         $name=mysql_result($result,0,"pic_name");
         $size=mysql_result($result,0,"size");
         $type=mysql_result($result,0,"type");
         $content=mysql_result($result,0,"content");
   
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
         header("Content-length: $size");
         header("Content-type: $type");
         echo $content;
    }
    else{
         die("No file ID given...");
    }
```

Comment: And what do you want from SO?

Comment: To tell me why im getting same value for all the images count value. I mean what is the flaw in my code!

Comment: What is your default value of count and data type of count in offers_em table?

Comment: 1. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. 2. Show us some kind of database structure or column names so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with SQL injection.

The problem is I'm calling the link in a loop,hence all the clicks values are getting updated.So i created a different **count_link.php** file and it will be called only when user click the image link.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM files";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         echo "<div class=single>
               <div class=wrap>
                   <a href=count_link.php?fid=".$offer_id.">
                       <img src=picture.php?fid=".$offer_id."\">
                   </a>
               </div>
               </div>";
    }
```

Anyways thanks for you time guys..:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that MySQL supports "+=", try
`SET count = count + 1`

EDIT: Definitely look into sorting the injection vulnerability regardless, as mentioned in the comments below your post.