# Button with a limit of one click per hour

Tags: php, database

i have a question With This simple system, i can make a button with a limit of one click per hour in php / sql or other? no limit per ip. but for all
It would be like a reservation system in real time, anyone can help me?
But only the script of the button with 1 click limit per hour for all.

Comment: You just need to store the last time it was pressed then see if someone has used it in the past hour and show a message instead of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the number of clicks in a mySQL column and increment it every time a user clicks the button and then check if the click falls in the past 1 hour interval and if so, tell them they have to wait.

Something like this:

```
select count(*) as clicks_in_the_past_hour
from table 
where click_time >= now() - interval 1 hour
```

Comment: Thanks for answered my question the problem is that my knowledge of php and mysql are null my idea is that when you press the button this redirects to the content in this situation would have to do?

Answer (score 0):

store click time to database then each click check click time with stored time if less than 1 hour then return false else return true and save then new time to database and so on.

Comment: How would you do? Something like this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358601/store-number-of-clicks-in-database-using-php) . I don't have idea

Answer (score 0):

Yes In java script you can do it. execute the following code.This code is for one minute,if you want time change ,change your require time in javascript code

```
<script>
  function doSomething() {
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
  setTimeout('document.getElementById("btn").disabled=false;',60000);//enter your require time in place of 60000
}
</script>


<label for="btn">This button will activate in one hour</label>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashraful Haque to answer.
The problem it's on reload the page this return activate...