# Limiting python script to run 15 times per hour in PHP

Tags: php, python, mongodb, twitter

I'm making a Twitter App and twitter makes it so any application won't run more than 15 times an hour. 
I execute a python script when a user presses a button that gets the top 5 trends on twitter.
I am using PHP and MongoDB NoSQL to store my data.
When I searched for an answer I came across --> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718744/button-with-a-limit-of-one-click-per-hour) but they are using a SQL DB.

My Question,

**How can I tell the user has executed the script 15 times within an hour?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the user runs the app, add their clicks to an object including its time.

When they run your script, pull these objects out, look through their dates, and delete everything with a timestamp more than an hour old and count the rest.